# What is the name of the DirectShow dataflow pattern?

Tags: python, directshow, dataflow

I am trying to code a simple filter chain in python that works well with multiple inputs (camera, keyboard, mouse) and outputs (video, audio).

I have previously developed DirectShow filters and I really like the architecture, but I have the feeling that it is too complex for my needs, though I might be mistaken.

Now I wonder if the type of architecture DirectShow is using, has a specific name or follows a certain design pattern. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find much.

Would anybody know where to start looking?

Answer (score 2):

DirectShow and other multimedia frameworks use a [pipeline model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(software)). This is a good way to get separation of concerns, because you can idealy use every pipeline element (filter in directshow) independent of others.